# Get value from cookie mvc

Tags: model-view-controller, cookies

I set value to Cookie in one mvc controler like this

```
        HttpCookie accessToken = new HttpCookie("AccessToken");
        accessToken.Values["accessToken"] = "cb7ca44ff81324186724867668572a8f";
        Response.SetCookie(accessToken);
```

When I get value from cookie in another controler like this

```
HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Get("AccessToken");
```

or like this

```
Request.Cookies["AccessToken"].Value
```

I get

> accessToken=cb7ca44ff81324186724867668572a8f

I just want to get value without key, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding key-value pair to AccessToken cookie. If you are storing just one value and don't need dictionary like structure, you can use `HttpCookie.Value` property.

```
accessToken.Value = "cb7ca44ff81324186724867668572a8f";
Request.Cookies["AccessToken"].Value // output 'cb7ca44ff81324186724867668572a8f'
```

**Update**: If you want to store multiple key-value pairs as you did initially, then:

```
var accessToken = new HttpCookie("AccessToken");
accessToken["somekey1"] = somevalue1;
accessToken["somekey2"] = somevalue2;

// read values
string somevalue1 = Request.Cookies["AccessToken"]["somekey1"];
string somevalue2 = Request.Cookies["AccessToken"]["somekey2"];
```

Comment: And if I am storing more than one value?